# VBA userform based on a selection made in a previous userform

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a macro in VBA that finds the word "Viewpoint" and produces a userform that looks in the surrounding cells (to the "North", "East", "South" or "West") and "converts" a 4-letter code into a 4-digit number, as long as the cell is "convertible".

It works using an array in the surrounding cells. As an example, the following would allow the user to convert the "North" and "East" cells, but would not convert "West" (being "nonconvertible") and would produce nothing for "South":

[image]

In this example, upon loading the macro, the user is presented with the following userform. Clicking on the "Convert North" or "Convert East" buttons produces a message box with the converted code, while clicking on "Convert West" produces a message box with the word "Nonconvertible".

[image]

However, rather than producing a message box, I'd like to produce a second userform, **based on the user's choice from the first userform**. e.g. If a user selects "Convert North", they'd receive a further userform with the converted code (as a label) and a couple of further options (as buttons, ideally just based on further indexes in the array). Of course this would mean that there would need to be some way of referencing the first userform in the second userform. I've had a look at other answers on here but can't seem to find one that works here. What would be a good way of doing this?

Here's the module code so far. Note that "optNorth", "optSouth", etc. refer to the userform buttons, while "lblNorth" etc. refer to the userform labels. Finally, feel free to let me know if you notice any way this code could be made more efficient:

```
Private Sub Surroundings(OFFSET_CELL As Range, LBL As Object, OPT As Object, DIRECTION As String)

    Dim VIEWPOINT As Range
    Dim LAST_ROW As Integer
    Dim ARR() As String

    ' Set ARR to use the "Split" function in the destination cell, making the "\" a delimiter
    ARR = Split(OFFSET_CELL, "\")

    ' Set the range in which to search for "Viewpoint"
    Set VIEWPOINT = Sheet1.Range("A1:Z26").Find(What:="Viewpoint", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)

    ' If there is a "\" in the adjacent cell...
    If InStr(1, OFFSET_CELL, "\") > 0 Then
        ' show a label with the DIRECTION and array index 0 (the 4-letter code)
        LBL.Caption = DIRECTION & " is " & (ARR(0))
        ' show a button label with the word "Convert" and the DIRECTION:
        OPT.Caption = "Convert " & DIRECTION

    ' In any other situation...
    Else
        LBL.Caption = DIRECTION & " is nothing."
        OPT.Caption = "Nothing"
        OPT.Enabled = False
    End If

End Sub
```

```
Public Sub Surroundings_Userform()

    Dim VIEWPOINT As Range

    ' Set the range in which to search for "Viewpoint"
    Set VIEWPOINT = Sheet1.Range("A1:Z26").Find(What:="Viewpoint", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)

    ' Load up the userform
    Load SurroundingsUserForm

    ' Call the variable code in the Surroundings sub
    Call Surroundings(VIEWPOINT.Offset(-1, 0), SurroundingsUserForm.lblNorth, SurroundingsUserForm.optNorth, "North")
    Call Surroundings(VIEWPOINT.Offset(1, 0), SurroundingsUserForm.lblSouth, SurroundingsUserForm.optSouth, "South")
    Call Surroundings(VIEWPOINT.Offset(0, 1), SurroundingsUserForm.lblEast, SurroundingsUserForm.optEast, "East")
    Call Surroundings(VIEWPOINT.Offset(0, -1), SurroundingsUserForm.lblWest, SurroundingsUserForm.optWest, "West")

    SurroundingsUserForm.Show

    Set VIEWPOINT = Nothing

End Sub
```

And here's the Form code:

```
Private Sub OptionButton(OPT_BUTTON As String, OFFSET_ROW As Integer, OFFSET_COLUMN As Integer)

    Dim VIEWPOINT As Range
    Dim ARR() As String
    Dim OFFSET_CELL As String

    ' Set the range in which to search for "Viewpoint")
    Set VIEWPOINT = Sheet1.Range("A1:Z26").Find(What:="Viewpoint", LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)

    Select Case True
        Case OPT_BUTTON
            ' Define OFFSET_CELL as per the option button
            OFFSET_CELL = VIEWPOINT.Offset(OFFSET_ROW, OFFSET_COLUMN)
            ' The array uses "\" as a delimiter
            ARR = Split(OFFSET_CELL, "\")
                ' If array index 1 is "Convertible", show a message box with array index 2
                If ARR(1) = "Convertible" Then
                    MsgBox (ARR(2))
                ' If array index 1 is "Nonconvertible", show a message box with "Nonconvertible"
                ElseIf ARR(1) = "Nonconvertible" Then
                    MsgBox ("Nonconvertible")
                ' In any other situation, unload the userform
                Else
                    Unload Me
                End If
    End Select

    Unload Me

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub optNorth_Click()
    Call OptionButton(optNorth, -1, 0)
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub optSouth_Click()
    Call OptionButton(optSouth, 1, 0)
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub optEast_Click()
    Call OptionButton(optEast, 0, 1)
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub optWest_Click()
    Call OptionButton(optWest, 0, -1)
End Sub
```

```
Private Sub optClose_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: So your question is how to reference one userform from another? `txtSecond = frmOne!txtFirst`

Comment: Since you're already passing `OFFSET_ROW` and `OFFSET_COLUMN` to `OptionButton` couldn't you simply make that sub load another userform with the desired input? If you also pass the address of `VIEWPOINT` you should have all the information you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood your question correctly please take a look at the example below.

I've set up the first userform as below

[image: First Userform]

and placed the following code behind it

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call Click("North")
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Call Click("South")
End Sub

Private Sub Click(str As String)
    Dim ufrm2 As UserForm2
    Set ufrm2 = New UserForm2
    ufrm2.CoOrd = str
    ufrm2.Show
End Sub
```

In the second form I've placed a textbox

[image: Second Userform]

with the following code

```
Option Explicit
Private vCoOrd As String
Property Let CoOrd(v As String)
        vCoOrd = v
End Property
Property Get CoOrd() As String
    CoOrd = vCoOrd
End Property

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    Label1.Caption = CoOrd
End Sub
```

Giving the following results:

[image]

This works by setting the `CoOrd` property of `UserForm2` from `UserForm1` before `Activating` the second userform. This way I'm able to pass values from `UserForm1` to `UserForm2` before the userform is displayed to the user